# MYSQL SELECT WITH LEFT JOIN LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join, limit

I have a problem: 
I want to select all babble-rooms where user1 or user2 are a specific user id. (`SELECT * FROM babble WHERE user1 = '$user' OR user2 = '$user'`)

But I also want to get the last entry of babble_messages where the babble ID is equal to babble_id.

My database structure:

> Table **babble**:
>      ID | user1 | user2 | created
>
> Table **babble_messages**:
>      ID | sender | babble_id | created | seen | message

My attempt is:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    babble
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        babble_messages.ID AS last_id, 
        babble_messages.sender AS last_sender, 
        babble_messages.babble_id, 
        babble_messages.created AS last_created, 
        babble_messages.seen AS last_seen, 
        babble_messages.message AS last_message
    FROM 
        babble_messages 
    ORDER BY 
        created DESC LIMIT 1
    ) babble_messages ON 
    babble.ID = babble_messages.babble_id 
WHERE 
    user1 = '$user' OR user2 = '$user' 
ORDER BY 
    last_created DESC
```

This outputs empty entries for the LEFT JOIN table. I think this happens because I select in the subquery just the last entry of babble_messages...
I tried to add a WHERE tag into the subquery but that throws an error:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    babble
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        babble_messages.ID AS last_id, 
        babble_messages.sender AS last_sender, 
        babble_messages.babble_id, 
        babble_messages.created AS last_created, 
        babble_messages.seen AS last_seen, 
        babble_messages.message AS last_message
    FROM 
        babble_messages 
    WHERE 
        babble.ID = babble_messages.babble_id* 
    ORDER BY 
        created DESC 
    LIMIT 
        1
    ) babble_messages ON 
    babble.ID = babble_messages.babble_id 
WHERE 
    user1 = '$user' OR user2 = '$user' 
ORDER BY 
    last_created DESC
```

In the subquery mysql does not know the "babble.ID".
How can I select just the last entry of babble_messages?

Of course I can use multiple request but I want to make just one request, because it is faster.

I hope this is enough information. :D 
Thanks for reading and hopefully answering :)

Have a nice day hadome

Comment: Can you format your query better? See [**How do I format my code blocks?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Sorry for these querrys, I hope that it's better now.

Comment: And tip 1: Never use `SELECT *`. Tip2: Where more than one table is used, always qualify column names, so `babble.user1`, for instance.

Comment: `I hope that it's better now.` lol it's better because i changed it

Comment: @Strawberry - Why shouldn't you use `SELECT *`.

Comment: @MakPo https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=evil+select+star&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=dVU1WcuMObP38Aed6aQg

Comment: Yes thank you @Peter

Comment: @Strawberry - Just quickly scanning the first link, it looks like the argument he is making is that it makes it harder to go back and know what you are getting from the table. The counter to that is, if you make a change in the table, you now have to hunt down every place the table was used and make the change there as well. It is a lot more work and that is bad practice. I'm not convinced `SELECT*` is 'evil' as the link you provided suggests. It is clean, easy to read, and lets the reader know that you are requesting everything. You are not missing any columns.

Comment: @MakPo Maybe you can send me the link to "why `SELECT *` is not as evil as everyone seems to think".

Comment: @Strawberry - I'm not a pro at SQL. I've just never heard anyone suggest that `SELECT *` was an issue. While looking through these links, they do make some good points. I doubt I'll stop using them all together, but I'll probably think more about it when I do use `*` in the future. I still think there are times when it is appropriate.

Comment: @makpo keep reading! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be somewhat slow if the number of users is massive, especially with the OR in there.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,user1
    ,user2
    ,created
    ,last_id
    ,last_sender
    ,babble_id
    ,last_created
    ,last_seen
    ,last_message
FROM
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,user1
        ,user2
        ,created
        ,(SELECT ID FROM babble_messages WHERE babble_ID = user1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1) AS babble_message_id
    FROM babble
    WHERE user1 = 1
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ID last_id
        ,sender last_sender
        ,babble_id
        ,created last_created
        ,seen last_seen
        ,message last_message
    FROM babble_messages
) b ON a.babble_message_id = b.last_id
ORDER BY last_created DESC
```

Comment: This throws: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'last_sender,
    ,babble_id,
    ,last_created,
    ,last_seen,
    ,last_messag' at line 7

Comment: Had a few extra commas.

Comment: Mysql does not know the column "babble.babble_message_id" in the on clause: #1054 - Unknown column 'babble.babble_message_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I kinda feel like I'm coding for you. I fixed the error though. I wrote this without running it because I don't have a dataset......

Comment: Sorry for making you feel like coding for me. But I was wondering why this throws an error...Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I fixed the mistake, I also tested it against a dataset I created. This should work now. Also, runs faster than I thought it might

Comment: why do you use subquery in second join?

Comment: It's not required. The original question specified using column aliases, which I kept in the subquery. These could ultimately be moved to the top query, but perhaps for readability the current version is best. It really makes no difference. The query engine should eliminate any unused columns either way, and in either case, the query returns every column.

Answer (score 0):

try to using table instance in your mysql query like **babble b** and **babble_message bm**

```
SELECT 
   b.* 
FROM 
   babble b
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
       bm.ID AS last_id, 
       bm.sender AS last_sender, 
       bm.babble_id, 
       bm.created AS last_created, 
       bm.seen AS last_seen, 
       bm.message AS last_message
    FROM 
       babble_messages bm
    WHERE 
       b.ID = bm.babble_id
    ORDER BY 
       created DESC 
    LIMIT 
       1
    ) bm ON 
    b.ID = bm.babble_id 
  WHERE 
    user1 = '$user' OR user2 = '$user' 
  ORDER BY 
    last_created DESC
```

I hope this may be helpful to you.